# Jquery: How to hold checkbox check / uncheck state in hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

i have a html table which i has many checkboxes. when user click on header checkbox then all child checkbox will be checked and unchecked based on header checkbox checked state.

user can uncheck and check any child checkbox too. i want to store child checkbox value in hidden field separated by comma. when child checkbox is selected then checkbox value will be store in hiiden field but if that checkbox value is in hiiden field then will not be store in hidden field.

when user uncheck anyone then that checkbox value will be removed from hidden field.

I tried this way but not successful. so guide me how to achieve it. my code as follows

```
<table id="tbl" border="10">
<thead>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id = "chckHead" /></td>
<td>First Row</td>
<td>Second Row</td>
<td>Third Row</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" value="101"/>
</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl"  value="102"/>
</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl"  value="103"/>
</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="hidden">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#chckHead').click(function () {
    $(".chcktbl").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  });  

  $(".chcktbl").change(function() {
  var values = [];
  $('.chcktbl').each(function (index, obj) {
  alert('pop');
    if (this.checked === true) {
      values.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
  });
  alert(values.toString());

});
```

Comment: how would you like the `string` that will be stored in the hidden `input` field to look like ? As this for example: `input ID: state, input ID: state, (...)` Or `input ID: value, input ID: value, (...)` ?

Comment: in hidden field checkbox value will be store like hiiden field= 101,102,103 etc

Comment: check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to assign the checkboxes values to the hidden `input` and also, you have to do so in the header checkbox event listener.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hidden = $('#hidden');
  $('#chckHead').click(function() {
    var state = $(this).prop('checked');
    if(state === false) {
      hidden.val('');
    }
    var vals = [];
    $('.chcktbl').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', state);
      if(this.checked === true) {
        vals.push($(this).val());
      }
    });
    hidden.val(vals.toString());
  });
  $(".chcktbl").change(function() {
    var values = [];
    $('.chcktbl').each(function(index, obj) {
      if(this.checked === true) {
        values.push($(this).val());
      }
    });
    hidden.val(values.toString());
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="tbl" border="10">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="chckHead" /></td>
      <td>First Row</td>
      <td>Second Row</td>
      <td>Third Row</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" value="101" />
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" value="102" />
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" value="103" />
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!--for the demo purpose, I changed the type of the input to 'text' to see the result, don't forget to change to 'hidden' again.-->
<input id="hidden" type="text" name="hidden">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: i guess you are close but you did not check if value is there then it should not be pushed to array and if uncheck any checkbox then value should be removed from array. am i right?

Comment: when you uncheck a checkbox its value is removed from the hidden input and to process the values you stored you should rely on the value of the the hidden input. The arrays that are used to populate the hidden input are reseted to empty when you check/uncheck any checkbox you have, so to process the values that you just inserted in the hidden input **DON'T** rely on the used arrays you should use the hidden input field's value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get all checked checkboxes with this selector:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

Then you can call map to get all the ids and join them

```
string = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(idx,element) {
    return element.value;
}).join(',')
```

Then just listen the onChange event for all checkboxes and set the value for the hidden field.